# Create new column from multi-line Regular Expression in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've done some searching, but I'm running into an issue with attempting to use regular expressions to extract multi-line text in a pandas dataframe column, and push those results to a new column.

I am attempting to extract everything between the two repeats of "QAT", which involves single line and m
multi-line sentences/text.

Example is below:

```
 Cust_ID                  Cust_Review
------------------------------------------------------
   101         "QAT - i dislike this toaster, it
                Never works right.\n This is the
                last time! - QAT"
-----------------------------------------------------
   201          "QAT - I love this toaster! - QAT"
-----------------------------------------------------
   301          "QAT - I bought this toaster for my
                 mother, which she loves.\n I will
                 also be buying another for\n my
                 sister, she could use it as well. - QAT"
```

What I'm trying to produce is this, extract out all in-between text into a new column within the dataframe:

```
 Cust_ID                  Cust_Review                                Newcolumn_Text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   101         "QAT - i dislike this toaster, it                i dislike this toaster, it
                Never works right.\n This is the            Never works right.\n This is the
                last time! - QAT"                           last time!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   201          "QAT - I love this toaster! - QAT"              I love this toaster!     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   301          "QAT - I bought this toaster for my             I bought this toaster for my
                 mother, which she loves.\n I will           mother, which she loves.\n I will
                 also be buying another for\n my             also be buying another for\n my
                 sister, she could use it as well. - QAT"    sister, she could use it as well.
```

I attempted doing so with regex, but I can tell I'm way off, and any help would be appreciated.

My failed attempt:

```
df['Newcolumn_Text'] = re.search(r'QAT.*QAT', df.Cust_Review, re.DOTALL)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `extract` does just what you want:

```
df['Newcolumn_Text'] = df['Cust_Review'].str.extract('QAT(.*)QAT', re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot.  Would this also work with extracting texting between any "whitespace characters" as well, so long as its in between 'QAT'? I presume it does. Thanks again!